# Actuar según el value de un boton

Tags: jquery

He creado un listado que se compone de diferentes checkbox, y un botón.

Cuando no hay ningún elemento seleccionado, el botón pone cerrar y si hay al menos uno seleccionado pone Guardar.

Lo que quiero es controlar que si finalmente pulsan este botón, si pone guardar me muestre un mensaje y si pone cerrar, me muestre otro mensaje.

Este es mi código, pero no funciona

```
$('#Btn').click(function(){
    var valor = $('#Btn').val;
    if(valor == "Guardar"){
        alert('Pone guardar');
    }else{
        alert('Pone cerrar');
    }
});
```

¡Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade los paréntesis a el método `.val()` sin argumentos.

Como dice Yikarus en los comentarios, cuando haces `.val` solo estás accediendo al método, y eso te regresa un string con el contenido del mismo. Necesitar hacer `.val()` para llamarlo.

Comment: Siiii, ¿Puedo preguntar cuando se paréntesis y cuando no? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando haces `.val` solo estás accediendo al método, y eso te regresa un string con el contenido del mismo. Cuando haces `.val()` estás mandándolo llamar/ ejecutándolo.